# How can I bundle javadoc/sources with an aar library

Tags: android, gradle, javadoc, android-studio-3.0, aar

I am publishing an open-source library for Android. I want to package the sources/javadoc with it so that users can see the documentation when using autocomplete in Android Studio.

I don't want users to have to manually import `sources.jar` files; I want this to happen automatically. [This link](https://medium.com/@hamen/android-library-aar-and-javadoc-6859898cad28) claims it can be done easily if the code is open-source, but it doesn't elaborate on how.

Can anyone explain how? The methods I've found in answers on SO and Google don't work for me. Here is my **build.gradle** which attempts to include the `sources.jar`, but it never gets included in the final .aar:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

task classesJar(type: Jar) {
    from "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/release"
}

artifacts {
    archives classesJar
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}
```